# Resize div width based on browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery. Below is my html structure, where the content and grid have css with a width of 100%. This works perfectly in IE8 whereas in firefox and google chrome the div width spans and has to scroll toward the right.

```
<div id="content">
     <div id="grid">
          <table id="test">
          </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

However i am using the below jquery function to dynamically resize div width based on browser for ff and chrome.but it's not working. Can anyone help me?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
     var windowWidth = $(window).width();
     $('content').css({'width':windowWidth });
});
.resize();
```

css post:

```css
#content{
     padding-right: 0px; 
     padding-left: 0px; 
     padding-bottom: 0px; 
     margin: 3px 28px 2px 14px; 
     width: 100%; 
     padding-top: 0px;
     height: 70%;
}
#grid {
    width: 100%;
    /* following rules for illustration */
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding-right: 0px; 
    padding-left: 0px;  
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px; 
    padding-top: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: `$('#content')` - note the `#` is the correct selector, but more to the point, why not use `width: 100%;` ?

Comment: DIVs take up 100% width by default as they are block level elements. Seems like you're over engineering the problem.

Comment: The width is 100% which spans or expands in ff and chrome but  not in IE and should dynamically resize for browsers

Comment: Might want to include some CSS because I don't see any issues in Chrome. Based on what you've described I've replicated your markup and CSS in a jsFiddle, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/fadkje2b/. No scrollbar.

Comment: @hungerstar you see the padding of the ```html``` or ```body``` element? Now he tries to set the div to the width of the window, which means any padding on html or body will lead to a scroll bar, IE8 however uses ```box-sizing: border-box;``` which solves this issue.

Comment: Updated the css http://jsfiddle.net/fadkje2b/2/

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard not sure what you're talking about. The jsFiddle I linked to has the default margin of 8px that is applied by Chrome to the body tag. No scrollbar. User must have additional CSS rules that are creating the scrollbar that they have not shared.

Comment: @hungerstar yes but you are using ```width:100%``` where as he is abusing javascript to get the width of the window which in chrome is width of body+16px and in turn gets a div 16px wider then the body. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLL5tqL8/

Comment: @mala you need to include that CSS in your post. What you have added to the jsFiddle changes things.

Comment: @mala change 100% to auto, see: http://jsfiddle.net/z53cnkeg/

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard how about not setting an explicit width to begin with as DIVs are block level and will take up the full width of their parent element?

Comment: @mala I updated my answer to reflect your css

Comment: @hungerstar Of course, I'm not arguing with you about that. Totally agree

Comment: @mala minor note -  you could simplify your CSS by using the shorthand property of padding like you did for margin. Also if you're setting something to `0px` you can just use `0`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're doing you shouldn't use javascript, you could just use `width: 100%;` or even better `width: auto;`.

That being said if you want to dynamically set a width in pixels using jquery you need to add the suffix `px`.

Which means:

```
$('content').css({'width':windowWidth+'px' });
```

I just don't think this is going to solve your initial problem where you get scroll bars when using `width:100%` or `width:auto;`

I think you need to do the following:

Remove the padding and margin for html and body using CSS as follows:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

or jquery

```
$("body").css("margin","0")
         .css("padding","0");
$("html").css("margin","0")
         .css("padding","0");
```

## Update

Now that you posted your CSS just change it to the following:

```
#content{
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; 
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px; 
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; 
    MARGIN: 3px 28px 2px 14px; 
    WIDTH: auto;  /* changed this line */
    PADDING-TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 70%;
}
#grid {
    width: auto; /* and changed this line aswell */
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 100px;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; 
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;  
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    MARGIN: 0px 0px 10px; 
    PADDING-TOP: 0px; 
}
```